# How can I differentiate between a click and a drag in Google Maps JS API v3 on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a mobile-capable HTML5 site with Bootstrap, jQuery and the Google Maps v3 API.

I've figured out most of the code, I want to be able to click, add a marker, HTTP POST that location to the server (for storing it).

I initially had trouble getting android to see that a click should happen on touch.

```
if ($.browser.mobile) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event) {
           placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });

} else { 

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

}
}
```

I'm using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ jQuery code to do the `$.browser.mobile` thing.

The problem I'm having is that if I click the map, to drag it, and move to a different location on mobile, it calls placeMarker(), which is understandable, if irritating, so the process of dragging the map creates markers (and POSTs to the server).

Is there any way I can detect, if a drag has taken place, so I can tell it to not bother doing placeMarker and POST?

Comment: Register for a mousemove event on mousedown. If mousemoves beyond a thresold do event.preventDefault on mouseup event.

Comment: @closure can you explain a bit more what you mean about registering for an event?

Comment: @closure means to create a listener (addListener) for the mousedown on the map. In the handler for this, check if the mouse moves some before allowing the calls to the server. If the mouseup happens in the same place as the mousedown (or thereabouts) then you haven't had a drag. Although, from what I remember, there are "drag" events in the GMaps API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if code like this will work for you:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event) {

  var initPoint = {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY}, 
      toBeCanceled = false, 
      latLong = event.latLong;

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
       var newPoint = {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY};

       // if newPoint has moved beyond expected limits
       toBeCanceled = true
    });  

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(event) {

      if (toBeCanceled) {
        event.preventDefault() // event.stop() seems to work as commented by OP
      } else {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
      }

      // Unregister mousemove and mouseup
    });

});
```

Comment: I had to change `event.preventDefault()` to `event.stop()`, but now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mousedown event, I would rather use `dragstart, dragend, drag` events.
You could also replace click with dblclick, if that does not impact the user experience you want to present to your users. I do not know how "click" interacts with the "drag" event.

Comment: Double clicks suck.  Especially on mobile.